# Git master branch in one repository and another branch on another private repository

Tags: git, github

Is it possible to use a public repository like github and have a branch exist on a private repository?

I want my master branch to be public, but I also want to work from a private branch (perhaps on another host) which I can work from.  Occasionally, I would like to pull updates from the master branch as it's updated.

Am I better off just using 'git clone'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you can decide which branch to push to a remote repository. Assuming your github repository is called `origin` you would push only `master` with

```
$ git push origin master
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use git push for that

$git push origin local_branch_name:remote_branch_name